# parent to child query

Tags: trigger

I have Operation parent object and DSC_Registration child object..I have Name_DSC_Applicant__c this custom picklist on child object..now I want first value of that pick list.i wrote this code please let me know 
I wrote code

```
Operation__c op = [select id,(select Name_DSC_Applicant__c
from DSC_Registration__c) from Operation__c
where id = 'a0E6F00001VYP6Z'];
system.debug('---Operation__c ID:---'+op.DSC_Registration__c[0].Name_DSC_Applicant__c);
```

Comment: If a below answer [addressed your problem](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) by clicking on the check mark/tick to the left of the answer, turning it green. This marks the question as resolved to your satisfaction, and awards [reputation](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) both to you and the person who answered. If you have >= 15 reputation points, you may also upvote the answer if you wish. There is no obligation to do either.

Answer (score 0):

[Parent to child](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm) can be accessed using relationship name which will be `DSC_Registration__r`

```
Operation__c op = [select id,(select Name_DSC_Applicant__c
from DSC_Registrations__r) from Operation__c
where id = 'a0E6F00001VYP6Z'];
system.debug('---Operation__c ID:---'+op.DSC_Registrations__r[0].Name_DSC_Applicant__c);
```

Comment: Thanx Himanshu..It's working

Comment: great.. close the question then

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to optimise the query so you can get only 1 item from the child items

```
Operation__c op = [select id,(select Name_DSC_Applicant__c from DSC_Registrations__r **Order By Createddate DESC LIMIT 1**) from Operation__c where id = 'a0E6F00001VYP6Z'];

system.debug('---Operation__c ID:---'+op.DSC_Registrations__r[0].Name_DSC_Applicant__c);
```